# Weird max min results for int column

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm using python 2.7.6  with sqlite 3.3.6.
I have a table with an INT column. When I select `max()` or `min()` over the column, some random number from the row is returned that is neither the min nor max. I've tried to reproduce this behavior, manually creating table and inserting the same values, min and max work perfectly. However, after my script, a manual query table gives weird results again.

Here is create table statement

```
CREATE TABLE customer_score ( DATE INT , SPAUBM INT , "CUSTOMER" TEXT, "SCORE" INT )
```

I use executemany method from sqlite to fill the table.

```
cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO customer_score VALUES ( ?, ?, ? , ? )", list_to_put)
```

Here is example of the row, that is put into table from file

```
 4203 6JASTYMPT 987335
```

Example of the issue :

```
sqlite> select *  from customer_score  where customer='AAA' and date in (20140219);
20140219|9214|AAA|5017262
20140219|9213|AAA|3409363
20140219|9207|AAA|2288238
20140219|9208|AAA|809365

sqlite> select max(score)  from customer_score  where customer='AAA' and date in (20140219);
809365

sqlite> select min(score)  from customer_score  where customer='AAAL' and date in (20140219);
2288238
```

Could it be that executemany method screws up the INT data somehow before insertion into the table?

I have no idea how can I check this.

UPDATE

SQlite manual says that `MIN()` `MAX()`  are shorcut to `ORDER BY LIMIT 1`. In my case , ORDER BY  also does not work as expected.  Rows position looks completely random.

```
sqlite> select *   from customer_score  where customer='AAA' and date in (20140218, 20140219) order by score desc  ;
20140219|9208|AAA|809365
20140218|9208|AAA|629937
20140219|9214|AAA|5017262
20140218|9214|AAA|3911855
20140219|9213|AAA|3409363
20140219|9207|AAA|2288238
20140218|9213|AAA|2127092
20140218|9207|AAA|1489895
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values in the `score` column are not numbers but strings.

You have to ensure that the values in `list_to_put` are actually numbers.

(Please note that SQLite pretty much [ignores the column data type](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html); it does not matter whether you declare it as `INT` or `TEXT` or `FLUFFY BUNNIES`.)

Comment: Thank you! I missed to check this. I was sure that if i feed sqlite with digit in string form to INT formatted column, it  will be converted to INT automagically  or throw exception. Regarding dates, as soon as format is YYYYMMDD, i can compare dates as digits, that is why i keep them in INT.